# Orbeon Forms - Dialog Control to Email

Tags: dialog, orbeon

I would like to prompt a message box that would consist of a label, text box and a button to email the form to the email address added in the text box when the Save button in Orbeon form is clicked. Is there a dialog control suitable for this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need to add your own dialog for this. I imagine that this is for a form you're creating with Form Builder. Then the good news is that the upcoming Orbeon Forms 2017.2 will have a new property, `oxf.fr.detail.dialogs.custom.*.*`, which will allow you to [include in your forms dialogs that you've defined in external files](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom.html).

Comment: Thank you. Yes my form is built using Form Builder. And I have been able to now prompt my own dialog box when the `save` button is clicked. Could you please help me send an email to the email address I am adding in the text box of my dialog when the button in my custom dialog box is clicked.

Comment: In a process, which runs when a button is pressed, you can run the [`email` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#email), which can send emails to users. Would this help?

Comment: Yes, but could you please tell me how to retrieve the email id added in that customized dialog control. And any coding samples to the button (Suppose `Send Email` ) for the customized dialog box button. Thank you.

Comment: See [this example](https://gist.github.com/avernet/ab887bccf7f366d56a0cca3182ee760b), but note that this requires the yet unreleased 2017.2 as it uses the `oxf.fr.detail.dialogs.custom.*.*` property.